# access tomcat virtual host from localhost

Tags: apache, tomcat7, virtualhost

i have apache configured with tomcat with two virtual hosts

```
<Host name="site1.com" appBase="/site1".../>

<Host name="site2.com" appBase="/site2".../>
```

Now site1 query data from site2 using http and both are on the same server. is there a way to make site1 query site2 using localhost or 127.0.0.1 IP? will 127.0.0.1:8080/site2 work?

Answer (score 1):

When you use virtual hosts, you will have to connect to the server using a host-name, and not the numeric IP.

If you want to access site2 on 127.0.0.1, you will make sure that "site2.com" resolves to `127.0.0.1` (on that machine).

An easy way of doing this on a single machine, can be to edit your `/etc/hosts`-file and simply add an entry that says "site2.com" has IP-address `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: thanks andrel, is there a way to make site2 externally accessible via site2.com but let site1 access site2 locally (i.e localhost)?

Comment: Yes, if your hosts-file (on your server) points site2.com to 127.0.0.1. This should only affect how site2.com are accessed *from that* server. As long as site2.com resolves to the correct *external* IP-address, external access should still work the way you expect.

Comment: ok so setting site2 VirtualHost to "<VirtualHost xx.xx.xxx.xxx:80 127.0.0.1:80>" will automatically use 127.0.0.1 is accessed locally and xx.xx.xxx.xxx if accessed from outside. am i making sense in this?